# AKCallbackInstrument midiIn and status on callback not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audiokit

I have upgraded AudioKit to 4.6.1 and now cannot compile my application. 2 issues came up are connected to the AKCallbackInstrument class.

first:

`callbackTrack?.setMIDIOutput(callbackInstrument.midiIn)` which comes up with `Value of type 'AKCallbackInstrument' has no member 'midiIn'` which is wiered because AKCallbackInstrument inherits from `AKMIDIInstrument`

second:

```
callbackInstrument.callback = { status, noteNumber, velocity in
    if(status == .noteOn){
        // ...
    }
}
```

this notes: `Ambiguous reference to member '=='` , this isuue I saw on SO already but nothing helped.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I got few questions personally I'll post here what worked for me as an accepted answer.

change `AKCallbackInstrument` with `AKMIDICallbackInstrument` and the API should work as expected.

* Please make sure you use a version that is newer than 4.6.1 as fixes and changes to MIDI components were made in this version release.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is due to the change from MIDIStatus being a type to MIDIStatus being an object contain a type.

```
public struct AKMIDIStatus {
    ...
    public var type: AKMIDIStatusType? {
        return AKMIDIStatusType(rawValue: Int(byte.highBit))
    }
```

So, try just changing your code to s

```
if status.type == .noteOn {
    //
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately this didn't work for me, as status and other arguments to the callback are for some reason interpreted as MIDIByte. The installing via cocoapods was always making me troubles with AudioKit, so for now I decided to download and set up the framework manually. Hopefully Carthage will be adopted soon. hope this helps me.